# Pip installing packages but module not found after install

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Hi I am running Ubuntu 16.04.
I have had problems with my pip, it seems like it is installing correctly but when I open python and go to import, it gives me an error saying it cannot be found.

I read other posts and it seems like pip is talking to the wrong version of python.

When I run:

```
>> which pip
/home/Username/.local/bin/pip

>> which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I tried uninstalling pip and then reinstalling it but when I run "which pip" it comes up the same location. I can't use this pip to download any python packages. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Edit:
When i put in the terminal the following commands the output is:

```
>> python -V
Python 2.7.12

>> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/heatdeath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: tell us `python -V` and `pip -V`